# Running cudaHashcat-1.33 on AWS g2.2xlarge - Error cuModuleLoad() 209 when trying cudaExample0.sh

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, cuda, nvidia, amazon-ec2

As it says in the description I have installed cudaHashcat-1.33 on an AWS g2.2xlarge instance.

I've used the .run file to install the CUDA Toolkit and then performed this test: deviceQuery ; as explained here in the official documentation (http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/index.html#running-binaries).

Then I installed cudaHashcat-1.33, following these instructions.

```
sudo apt-get install p7zip-full
wget http://hashcat.net/files/cudaHashcat-1.33.7z
7za x cudaHashcat-1.33.7z
cd cudaHashcat-1.33
```

Then I tried to run this: `cudaExample0.sh` in `~/cudaHashcat-1.33/cudaExample0.sh` and I end up getting this output:

```
cudaHashcat v1.33 starting...

Device #1: GRID K520, 4095MB, 797Mhz, 8MCU
Device #1: WARNING! Kernel exec timeout is not disabled, it might cause you errors of code 702

Hashes: 6494 hashes; 6494 unique digests, 1 unique salts
Bitmaps: 16 bits, 65536 entries, 0x0000ffff mask, 262144 bytes
Applicable Optimizers:
* Zero-Byte
* Precompute-Init
* Precompute-Merkle-Demgard
* Meet-In-The-Middle
* Early-Skip
* Not-Salted
* Not-Iterated
* Single-Salt
* Scalar-Mode
* Raw-Hash
Watchdog: Temperature abort trigger set to 90c
Watchdog: Temperature retain trigger set to 80c


ERROR: cuModuleLoad() 209
```

A second example is this one, where I actually use the file I want to attack.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-58-154:~$ ~/maskprocessor/src/mp64.bin ?l?l?l?l?l?l?l?l | ~/cudaHashcat-1.33/cudaHashcat64.bin -m 2500 xxx.hccap
cudaHashcat v1.33 starting...

Device #1: GRID K520, 4095MB, 797Mhz, 8MCU
Device #1: WARNING! Kernel exec timeout is not disabled, it might cause you errors of code 702

Hashes: 1 hashes; 1 unique digests, 1 unique salts
Bitmaps: 8 bits, 256 entries, 0x000000ff mask, 1024 bytes
Rules: 1
Applicable Optimizers:
* Zero-Byte
* Single-Hash
* Single-Salt
Watchdog: Temperature abort trigger set to 90c
Watchdog: Temperature retain trigger set to 80c


ERROR: cuModuleLoad() 209
```

*nvidia-smi*

```
[root@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx cudaHashcat-1.33]$ nvidia-smi
Wed Mar  4 19:07:35 2015       
+------------------------------------------------------+                       
| NVIDIA-SMI 340.32     Driver Version: 340.32         |                       
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GRID K520           On   | 0000:00:03.0     Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   43C    P8    17W / 125W |     10MiB /  4095MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Compute processes:                                               GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Process name                                     Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running compute processes found                                         |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

If someone knows what is going on, I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: a little [bit of googling](https://twitter.com/hashcat/status/565119465990656001) suggests to me a problem (mismatch) between your loaded driver (too old) and the one that cuda hashcat is expecting to properly load the (precompiled) modules.  Which GPU driver version do you have loaded and which CUDA version are you using?  (Pasting the output of deviceQuery and nvidia-smi into your post might help.)  I note the following on the [hashcat page](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat/): "GPU Driver requirements:
NV users require ForceWare 346.x or later "

Comment: Okay, so I've added the nvidia-smi output and it states that the driver version is 340.32, which seems to be the problem. However (even I feel idiotic asking this) I can't seem to find the driver. How would I go about updating it?

Comment: go to [www.nvidia.com](http://www.nvidia.com), click on Drivers...All NVIDIA Drivers...then select GRID...GRID Series...Grid K520...Linux 64-bit...then click search.  I do that and I get [this](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/82252/en-us) (<-- click here) 346.47 driver.  You could also just install CUDA 7 RC which will carry the 346.29 driver (or newer) along with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after a lot of searching through forums I finally found an answer. @Robert Crovella, thanks for pointing out that the driver was the wrong one. So it turns out that finding the linux drivers for NVIDIA is not that easy, but I came across this [page](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/01/install-nvidia-346-35-ubuntu-1404/), which then lead me to the [Linux Drivers of NVIDIA](http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html). Just download the driver required for your architecture (if you use wget click on 'Download' first, since there is an acceptance page). After that do 'chmod +x nvidia-driver.run' and then install it with 'sudo ./nvidia-driver.run'.

Hope that my experience helps someone else.

Comment: For me it was because I was using legacy cudaHashcat (1.36). Using 1.37 fixed my issues.